# Non-Graphical Tool for OWL Language

Tags: semantic-web, owl

I am currently doing a project and I have to work with OWL. I have graphical tools like Protege and OntoStudio, but I need a non-graphical one. A tool that I can work with as I code in Eclipse or Turbo-C directly, Not but createing diagrams and convert it to the owl code. Can I find such a tool?

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. Do you need an Eclipse plugin that offers syntax highlighting and intellisense for your favorite OWL syntax? In this case, what is your favorite OWL syntax? What role does "Turbo-C" play?

Comment: In graphical tool, I can create a diagram and then the tool can convert my diagram to the code. I need something that makes me able to write my codes directly in a code environment. I was searching for a non-graphical tool that also checks the syntax of my code and like eclipse or similar tools, make me able to find the errors easily. Unfortunately I could not find such a tool. I decided to write my codes in a RDFEditor and check it accuracy using Protégé. Turbo-C just was an example of a tool that we can directly write codes, run them and find the existing errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, I usually edit using Protege (which also allows you to edit the code directly)

- Some vim owl tools: https://github.com/mattpap/vim-owl-tools, seems to be abandoned
- A plugin for Protege that allows you to edit directly: http://www.co-ode.org/downloads/manchesterowlsyntaxeditor/
- Another one, based on Eclipse: http://owl-eclipse.projects.semwebcentral.org/html/userguide/tasks-3.1.html

You can also work with notepad++ or any text editor

My suggestion is: use Protege with any plugin to make the code edition easier, or begin with protege and then edit the generated file as you like

Comment: The github link is broken and I can't find it... :( Does anyone know where this resource has been moved to (or have a copy/clone of it)?